# Will Flex Viewer work after Arc upgrade?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

My organization is in the process of upgrading our ArcGIS server to 10.4.1 along with Arc Desktop, Catalog, etc.  We use ArcGIS viewer for Flex for all internal applications.  I read the list of deprecated features for Arc 10.3 and 10.4 and saw that the Flex Viewer was one of them.  I understand that Flex hasn't received support or an update since 2014/15.  My question is, if we upgrade our software to 10.4.1, will the Flex viewer simply not work anymore?  These applications are crucial to daily tasks and I do not want them to stop working once we upgrade to 10.4.1.  I am in the process of putting our GIS applications in the Javascript API but with all of the different applications we use, it will take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

What version of ArcGIS Server are you currently on? I have done something similar upgrading from Server 10.1 to 10.3.1 and I didn't have a problem. You should generally be OK but it would be a good idea to do the upgrade on a test environment first. This is what I did.

The flex viewer consumes the ArcGIS Server REST API. This is what will get upgraded when you do upgrade ArcGIS Server. Your flex viewer apps won't change and once the new Server REST API doesn't have any breaking changes to it the flex apps can continue to consume the api without problem. [Here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/What_s_new_in_the_ArcGIS_REST_API/02r3000000q6000000/) is the change log for the various versions of the REST API. Generally new features are added but old ones are not removed to preserve compatibility.

But I can't stress enough to do this in a test environment first.

Comment: We're on 10.1 for everything and will upgrade to 10.4.1 for everything